Buck Converter Coss Loss Equation
Why is the LS output cap not accounted for the loss due to output capacitance (Coss)?
In my mind, the LS cap is being charged by the pmoss, just as the HS cap is being discharge by the PMOS. For example, if I add a 100uF cap from Vsw to gnd, why would that not show up in Coss losses? If that is accounted as a separate loss, why is the LS Coss not considered as part of the Coss loss?
Further, Why is HS Coss = Cds-H + Cgd-H, I would have thought it is Gds-H + Cgs-H instead, as they are exposed to the output.



"pmoss"? PMOS? The diagram shows only NMOS.

Source for the graphic?

If the output current is positive and sufficient, the inductor current slews the switch node to ~ground during the dead time before the lower switch turns on, so it's very nearly zero-voltage switched on turn-on.

Sorry my design has pmos hs and nmos ls…

I understand that the LS coss discharging is lossless, but so is the charging of the HS coss. But when the transition is from low to high, the LS is charged up via the HS and that should cause loss. But it’s not considered here. Why?

@Mehdi - Hi, As commented above, where did those images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original sources are online & public, please [edit] the question & add each name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (or a private intranet) then give full details of the sources e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. || Always reference to the best of your ability. TY

This is just one of the many loss components of a Buck converter.  It is one of the loss components of the high side switch.
When the low side switch is closed, the voltage across the parallel combination of Cds-h and Cgd-h is Vin, because both the gate and the source are pulled to ground.  Each of the capacitors have energy equal to 1/2CV^2 joules.
When the high side switch is closed, this energy is dissipated in Ron-h of the high side switch as heat and is lost.
Since this event occurs at your switching frequency, you must multiply this event by the frequency to get to joules per second (watts).
However, when the high side switch is turned off, the low side capacitance Cds-L is discharged into your load (not lost) until the body diode starts to conduct and the voltage across this capacitor equals the Vd.  Then the low side switch turns on, and only a small amount of charge remains.  I suppose that theoretically this small charge could be dissipated in Ron-L if the on resistance was small enough.

Thank you for taking the time to explain in steps as you did. Could you explain why the LS cap charging up as the HB is being pulling high by the HS switch is not accounted for on the loss?

It is because this cap is discharged through the inductor and into the load when the high side switch opens.  You are correct that it must be charged each cycle, but this energy is not lost.
